# UWP: Can't type in Textboxes upon navigation to new page

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm facing a weird issue with my UWP app, where if I navigate to a new page using Frame.Navigate(), the textbox on the page has focus but I'm not able to type anything within it. However, I'm able to delete or backspace the current text.

Furthermore, I'm able to type into the textbox after click outside or clicking onto another text box and then back to it. The same occurs when tabbing across the text boxes.

I experience the same problem even with new pages with nothing but a single textbox.

My Target and Min builds are 16299.

I have tried to change the build targets to newer and older versions. Also created a new UWP project which a blank page with a text box and navigated to it and the problem does not occur here

Comment: I created a blank app for testing above issue, unfortunately, I could not reproduce it , could you share [mcve] for us?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I will remember to include minimal reproducible example next time. But I found this particular bug in my code was hard to track down as there was no inherent errors, just behavioural issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving my own problem...

The problem was caused by the property `FocusOnKeyboardInput="True"` that was specified for a search textbox within my Splitview pane on my main page. So when I was selecting a listview item and navigating to a new page, it wasn't focusing on the textboxes on those pages upon loading.

I simply removed `FocusOnKeyboardInput="True"` property altogether from that search textbox and it fixed the problem.